# ffmpeg thumbnails with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, java, ffmpeg

I'm using the code below to generate thumbnails from videos.
It generates one image with 4 frames. The problem is that it does not seek between the frames so the 4 frames are the same. I guess I must use `select` instead of `-ss` but I can't figure out how.

```
// - inPath: path to video file
// - outPath: path to thumbnail, no thumbnail will be generated when absent
// - count: number of thumbs to generate
self.exec = function (inPath, outPath, count, handler) {
    var args = outPath ? [
        '-i', inPath ,
        '-f', 'image2',
        '-vframes', count || 1,
        '-aspect', '4:3',
        '-filter:vf', 'scale=\'if(gt(a,4/3),128,-1)\':' + 
           '\'if(gt(a,4/3),-1,96)\',' + 
           'pad=w=128:h=97:x=(ow-iw)/2:y=(oh-ih)/2:color=black,tile=4x1',
        '-y',
        '-ss', '15',
        outPath
    ] : [
        '-i', inPath
    ];
```

Comment: Unrelated protip: argument order in `ffmpeg` matters, do the `ss` flag before the `i` flag, because it's a much much faster seek. Also, I usually have a bash script or such generate the thumbnails into a basic file structure (e.g. `/media/<video id>/seek-thumbs/0.jpg`, so javascript would just calculate based off the media.

Comment: See https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Create%20a%20thumbnail%20image%20every%20X%20seconds%20of%20the%20video

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got that to work.

```
mdata = ffprobe(function(metadata){ },inPath)

        var parts = mdata['duration'].split(":");
        var hours = parts[0];
        var minutes = parts[1];
        var seconds = parts[2];
        var durationSec = 3600 * parseFloat(hours) + 60 * parseFloat(minutes) + parseFloat(seconds);

        var distance = Math.round(durationSec/5);       

        var args = outPath ? [
            '-ss', distance ,
            '-i', inPath ,
            '-f', 'image2',
            '-vframes', count || 1,
            '-aspect', '4:3',
            '-filter:vf', 'select=\'isnan(prev_selected_t)+gte(t-prev_selected_t\\,'+ distance +')\',' + 'scale=\'if(gt(a,4/3),206,-1)\':' + 
            '\'if(gt(a,4/3),-1,154)\',' + 
            'pad=w=206:h=155:x=(ow-iw)/2:y=(oh-ih)/2:color=black,tile=4x1',
            '-y',



            outPath
        ] : [
            '-i', inPath
        ];
```